# Java: Cases with "break;" inside IF-scope

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

**Case:**
I have been downloading a .java-file and inside I find a switch-statement that I find a bit complex.
I believe the author is using case-falltrough in this part of the code:

**Example of the code:**

```
case 2862:  
 . . if (array[6] == 3 && array[5] == 3) {  
 . . . . sendMessage("Good day!");  
 . . . . break;  
 . . }  
case 1513:  
case 1515:  
case 1517:  
case 1519:  
case 1521:  
 . . if (array[6] == 1 && array[5] == 2) {  
 . . . . sendMessage("Good night!");  
 . . . . break;  
 . . }
```

.
**Question:**
We can see the author(s) have placed some break;-statements inside the if-statements.
What is the practical difference between this style and placing the break;-statement outside the if-statement like this?

```
case 2862:  
 . . if (array[6] == 3 && array[5] == 3) {  
 . . . . sendMessage("Good day!");  
 . . }  
break;
```

Is it that if the if-statement is false and not run, the thread will move to the other cases instead of exiting the switch-statement?

Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Your suspected answer is exactamundo what's happening.